# Spinner acting out

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

Any ideas of what is happening here? Why does the purple box position itself outside the spinner for a moment there?
[image: Inspecting spinner]

This is my css and rotate animation:

```css
.spinner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.spinner-ball {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background: transparent !important;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
    <div class="spinner-ball" />
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem/question? The rotation works fine as far as I can see. It just seems to be the debugger glitching.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to be sure it is the debugger and not my styling. In some cases I saw the parent div growing in height but it is to be expected when the child's square element is rotated 45 degrees